# creating stripe connected subscriber account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to first create a stripe account, then create the subscription and customer via the created account ID, and then ultimately link the two to create a 'connected' subscriber account on stripe and for it to appear under my connected accounts in my dashboard. So far the script is failing.

```
            // Include Stripe PHP library
require_once 'stripe-php/init.php';

// Set API key
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($STRIPE_API_KEY);

    // Create Account
try {
    $stripe = \Stripe\Account::create(array(
        "email" => $email,
        "country"  => "US",
        "type"  => "custom",
        'capabilities' => [
        'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
        'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
    ],
    ));

// Add customer to stripe
try {
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        "email" => $email,
        "source"  => $token
    ), array("stripe_account" => $stripe->id));

}catch(Exception $e) {
    $api_error = $e->getMessage();
}

if(empty($api_error) && $customer){

    // Convert price to cents
    $priceCents = round($planPrice*100);

    // Create a plan
    try {
        $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
            "product" => [
                "name" => $planName
            ],
            "amount" => $priceCents,
            "currency" => $currency,
            "interval" => $planInterval,
            "interval_count" => 1
    ), array("stripe_account" => $stripe->id));

    }catch(Exception $e) {
        $api_error = $e->getMessage();
    }


    if(empty($api_error) && $plan){
        // Creates a new subscription
        try {


        $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
        "customer" => $customer->id,
        "items" => ["plan" => $plan->id]), array("stripe_account" => $stripe->id));

        }catch(Exception $e) {
            $api_error = $e->getMessage();
        }

        echo $api_error;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  "*So far the script is failing*" - what does this mean? How is it failing? Nothing happens? Errors? Account is created but subscriber is not? ... Edit your question, add details.  The code does not ever seem to do anything with `$api_error`, is that displayed or logged somewhere not shown?

Comment: `"country"  => US, "type"  => custom` - looks like typos here, both those values should be quoted.

Comment: I've never used the `accounts` API but [checking the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create), it says: "*capabilities
REQUIRED FOR CUSTOM ACCOUNTS*".  It looks like you're creating a `custom` account, but not passing the `capabilities` parameter.

Comment: I have display errors set to on however I'm not seeing anything regarding an api error on submission. I'm assuming I'm not calling a stripe call correctly or their is a parse error somewhere.

Comment: You can also try to locate your error from Stripe Dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs